# How to convert two different formats of date time values present in one column to one format?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, date

I have a column consisting of two formats: yyyymmdd (for eg., 20210513.0) and 5-digit format(for eg. 44351). I want both of these formats converted to one - `"%d/%m/%Y"`

I am able to convert the yyyymmdd format to required format by doing the following,

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce').dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

But by doing this I lose the 5-digit date. How may I convert both of these format to one by using pandas/python?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert both formats separately, for second is used `unit` with `origin` parameters for convert excel style datetimes and then replace missing values by another datetimes in [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[20210513.0,44351.0]})

d1 = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce')
d2 = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], unit='D', origin='1899-12-30', errors='coerce')

df['date'] = d1.fillna(d2).dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") 
print (df)
         date
0  13/05/2021
1  04/06/2021
```